# Tree.getType() method not found in antlr4.7

Tags: antlr4

We are trying to upgrade antlr from antlr-3.3 to antlr-4.7 in our application and found that getType method does not exist in Tree class any more. Could any of you let me know whats the alternative method of  getType from Tree class can be used to get token type for tree parsing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```java
    if (tree instanceof ParserRuleContext) {
        token = ((ParserRuleContext) tree).getStart(); // or #getStop
    } else if (tree instanceof TerminalNode) {        // TerminalNodeImpl or ErrorNode
        token = ((TerminalNode) tree).getSymbol();
    }
```